# Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Glacier\Exception\GlacierException: AWS Error Code: , Status Code: 400, AWS Request

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services

I've been trying to upload image through the SDK but i get this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\Glacier\Exception\GlacierException: AWS Error Code: , Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: , AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: , User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.4.3 Guzzle/3.7.2 curl/7.15.5 PHP/5.3.8 thrown in /www/site/test/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91

And this is my test code:

```
 <?php
 // Include the SDK using the Composer autoloader
 require 'aws-autoloader.php';
  use Aws\Glacier\GlacierClient;

    $client = GlacierClient::factory(array(
     'key'    => 'xxxxxxx',
     'secret' => 'xxxxxxxx',
     'region' => 'us-east-1' // (e.g., us-west-2)
    ));

    $vaultName = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx/vrs/images/album/default/pp.jpg';
    $filename = '/www/site/test/pp.jpg';

   $result = $client->uploadArchive(array(
     'vaultName' => $vaultName,
     'body'      => fopen($filename, 'r'),
    ));
    $archiveId = $result->get('archiveId');

    var_dump($archiveId);
```

**Any help is greatly appreciated :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may be confused about the difference between vaults and archives. You should make sure to look through the [Amazon Glacier Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/introduction.html) to become familiar with the basic concepts of Glacier. You must first create a vault in order to upload archives to it. A vault in Glacier is similar to a bucket in S3.

You should also check out these links which provide code samples for doing uploads with Glacier:

- [Uploading Archives to Amazon Glacier from PHP](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx7PFHT4OJRJ42/Uploading-Archives-to-Amazon-Glacier-from-PHP) blog post on the AWS PHP Developer Blog
- ["Amazon Glacier SDK php"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574390/amazon-glacier-sdk-php) post on SO